# Finished shave horse with linseed oil; now it is too slippery to hold work well

Tags: finishing

I built this simple shave horse following Rex Kreuger [plans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqudWoT_jkg); it is made from kiln-dried spruce. It worked great (as far as I can tell, first time using one!) once completed.

Since I will be storing it in a barn whose roof is getting leakier and leakier, I wanted to finish it in a way that would provide some basic protection if water was standing on it for a few days. (It will be covered by a tarp, but mice eat the tarp, etc). Raw linseed oil is all that was available in my shop, so I used that.

I finished it as I usually do, flooding the surface and waiting 15 or so minutes, then wiping down any excess. Then I come back after another 20 minutes and wipe down any excess, continuing to do this for the rest of hte day every hour or so.

The next day the linseed oil is looking nice, and clearly has begun to cure.

However, it is much less better at holding work now that the surfaces are a little harder and oilier. Chair legs will slip a bit when I'm working a knot, etc. Mostly the block below the angled working-surface slides towards me, loosening the hold and forcing to kick my legs out further and further to keep the same pressure on the piece.

I've tried sanding down the points-of-contact where sliding has occurred, but this doesn't work very well.

How can I remedy this? I've considered trying to permanently affix sandpaper or another grippy material to the block, or even re-making the block part (although I have no scrap material left over, so this would be an errand and an extra expense).

As a sub-question, how *should* I have treated the shave horse (if at all) to make it better withstand the elements?

Thanks! [image: image of shave horse]

Comment: Sand more coarsely, or line it with leather.

Comment: *"how should I have treated the shave horse (if at all) to make it better withstand the elements?"* Tricky question. Perhaps nothing? I'd probably want to finish it myself but not sure what I'd use here. Just so you know, linseed oil is basically a cosmetic finish. It does very very little to really protect wood. Even if applied the old-timey way, built up over many weeks (way more than a dozen coats) and then allowed to cure for a month it's *still* not very resistant to water. And in addition in a damp environment the wood is *more* prone to fungal attack than it was before you started o_O

Comment: lol yes i thoroughly regret doing linseed oil!

Comment: All is not lost by any means, you can cover it with a film finish (thinly) and it should prevent a lot of issues. As odd as it sounds shellac could be used here, but dilute poly would be my finish of choice for this because it's so easy to apply over larger areas and dries nice and hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried sanding down the points-of-contact where sliding has occurred, but this doesn't work very well.
> How can I remedy this?

Sand more coarsely (cross-grain, using 80 grit or lower), or line it with leather.

You could also line with cork or crubber which both give great hold, but expect to have to replace either far more frequently than leather.

> As a sub-question, how *should* I have treated the shave horse (if at all) to make it better withstand the elements?

This is a tricky question because the answer is as much opinion as anything.

From what I've seen, many shave horses — even those that seem to be left outside some or all of the time — are left unfinished so no finish at all is a viable option, even with the horse not being made from pressure-treated wood<sup>1</sup>.

Given the storage conditions I'd probably want to finish it myself, though I'm not sure what I'd have picked (although not BLO by itself<sup>2</sup>). I may have gone with a couple of coats of spar varnish thinned to wiping consistency (or a dilute mix of BLO and poly, which would be nearly the same thing).

There are a large number of wood-treatment products for exterior projects, garden furniture, decks, fences and sheds and any type of those — penetrating sealant, exterior varnish, "teak oil", deck sealants etc. — must be viable options. And although nobody seems to paint theirs a shave horse could obviously be painted given how well paint protects the exterior woodwork on houses, barns etc.

---

<sup>1</sup> Despite the expectation that this will be regularly wet, without direct exposure to the weather and not in contact with soil I'd expect this to *easily* last a decade.

<sup>2</sup> Linseed oil (regardless whether raw, heat-treated or with metallic driers) does very very little to really protect wood. Even if applied the old-timey way, built up over many weeks to more than a dozen coats and then allowed to cure for a month it's *still* not very resistant to water. And in addition, in a damp environment, wood treated with linseed oil is more prone to fungal attack than it was left bare.